# Bitbucket hook build from branch does not work for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I have Jenkins with a job for SonarQube analysis, with the following value:

```
GIT SSH URL - set correctly
Branch Specifier - "**"
```

In Bitbucket, I have given the following value:

```
Jenkins URL - http://101.101.101.101:8080/Jenkins
Skip SSL Certificate - Enabled
Omit SHA1 Hash Code - Unchecked
Omit Branch Name - Unchecked
Omit the Trigger Build Button - Unchecked
Advanced Config:
Committers to Ignore - Blank
Branch Options - Build All selected and Blank field
```

**I want Bitbucket to trigger Jenkins only if code is merged (from a pull request) to particular branch.**

I tried the following settings in Bitbucket:

```
Branch Options - Build From selected and "release/Integeration" in the field
```

Still changes to every branch is triggered.

I tried this in Bitbucket:

```
Branch Options - Build From selected and "ref/heads/release/Integeration" in the field
```

Now nothing gets triggered.

Comment: 1. Did you use HOOK from BitBucket with the plugin Parameterized Builds for Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use HOOK from Bitbucket with the plugin *[Parameterized Builds for Jenkins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213179/parameterized-builds-for-jenkins)* and assuming you set a job using that plugin in Bitbucket. If so, did you define the pull request (PR) trigger only?

[image]

[image]

[image]